# Scala: No Json serializer found for type Any

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following code.  Here is the schema for vesselFlagCountryDF

```
root
 |-- flagcountry: string (nullable = true)
 |-- max(count): long (nullable = true)
 |-- min(count): long (nullable = true)
 |-- avg(count): double (nullable = true)
 |-- stddev_samp(count,0,0): double (nullable = false)
```

And here are some sample rows:

```
+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------------+
|         flagcountry|max(count)|min(count)|avg(count)|stddev_samp(count,0,0)|
+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------------+
|              Cyprus|        65|        46|      55.0|      9.40744386111339|
|          Luxembourg|         3|         1|       2.5|    0.9999999999999999|
|                Niue|         5|         3|       4.4|    0.8944271909999159|
|           Palestine|         2|         1|      1.25|   0.49999999999999994|
|              Norway|        30|        18|      23.4|     5.683308895353129|
|            Mongolia|        21|        15|      17.6|     2.302172886644268|
|            Dominica|         1|         1|       1.0|                   0.0|
|British Virgin Is...|         1|         1|       1.0|                   NaN|
+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------------+
```

Now stddev("count") can either be a Double or Nan.

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}

  val vesselFlagCountryDF =
    vtype.groupBy("flagcountry").agg(max("count"), min("count"), avg("count"), 
                  stddev("count"))

  vesselFlagCountryDF.collect().foreach(row => {
    val flagCountry = row.getString(row.fieldIndex("flagcountry"))
    val upper: Long = row.getLong(row.fieldIndex("max(count)"))
    val lower: Long = row.getLong(row.fieldIndex("min(count)"))
    val mean: Double = row.getDouble(row.fieldIndex("avg(count)"))
    val stdDevWrapper: Any = row.get(row.fieldIndex("stddev_samp(count,0,0)"))
    val stdDev = stdDevWrapper match {
      case d: Double => d
      case _  => "NaN"
    }

    val json: JsValue = Json.obj(
      "type" -> "statistics",
      "name" -> "vesselCountByFlagCountry",
      "flagCountry" -> flagCountry,
      "timeInterval" -> Json.obj("startTime" -> startTime, "endTime" -> endTime),
      "upper" -> upper,
      "lower" -> lower,
      "mean" -> mean,
      "stdDev" -> stdDev
    )
```

On this line:

```
      "stdDev" -> stdDev
```

I get the following error:

```
No Json serializer found for type Any. Try to implement an implicit Writes or 
Format for this type. 
[error]           "stdDev" -> stdDev
```

What is the best way to handle this mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following term can only be inferred as `Any` as there is no parent type to unify `Double` and `String`, which is not recommended.

```
val stdDev = stdDevWrapper match {
  case d: Double => d
  case _  => "NaN"
}
```

On the other side, the JSON serialization only works with typed values, which not the case of an `Any` value.

The `stdDev` can be refactored to directly write the proper JSON value according the case.

```
val stdDev: JsValue = stdDevWrapper match {
  case d: Double => Json.toJson(d)
  case _  => Json.toJson("NaN")
}
```